# Jest - How to get more details on a non stopping test?

Tags: angular, jestjs

I use jest to test an Angular 11.2.6 app recently migrated from 8 to 11. Jest version is :

"jest": "^26.6.3",
"jest-preset-angular": "^8.4.0"

I run jest, most of my tests pass, but I have three tests keeping running infinitely.

[image]

I don't have any clue about the involved error in the logs.

By adding comment on the corresponding html file, I realized that to delete one particular type of div (two customized component from external library) in particular in each file, the tests pass. However, those divs also exist on other tested files, and I don't see any difference between them.

Would you have a clue, to have more details in the logs for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get into details, I had to run specifically each test using this command :

npm run test -- name-test

Problem solved, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is caused by some promise not resolving. If you’re using Observables or Promises, make sure that you’re running your test inside a `fakeAsync` block.